# Page element sliding

Tags: css, width, position, slide

I had to manually place a Twitter widget in my theme and I have it in the perfect place but it will slide left and right depending on the zoom level of the page.

How can I set the position of it to not move and stay in its position relative to the edge of the page and the text.

URL: http://silentcalltone.com/

Thanks

PS: The css im using for that element:" .twitter {position:relative;float:right;top: 720px;right: 100px;  position: absolute; } "

Comment: By "Zoom Level" do you mean the size of the browser window? Your twitter text seems to disappear when the window size shrinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simply:

```
position: relative
top: -140px;
left: 600px;
```

There are some other padding and margin issues on that page, as well as illegal HTML that you might want to fix before doing this though.  For example, this isn't allowed:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <div class="twitter">...</div>
</ul>
```

You can't nest divs inside uls

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is now is a fixed position. However, it will slide off the page to the right when zoomed in? Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: change the style on .twitter to the style I wrote above.  delete the float and position: absolute.